# The image must be a file of type: jpeg, bmp, png, jpg. in laravel 5.5

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.5

I don't understand why it's not working and getting me error

here is my form

```
{!! Form::open(['method' => 'PUT', 'route' => ['admin.project.edit', $project->slug, 'files' => 'true']]) !!}

                      <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('title') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                    {!! Form::label('title', 'Title') !!}
                    {!! Form::text('title', $project->title, ['class' => 'form-control', 'required' => 'required']) !!}
                    <small class="text-danger">{{ $errors->first('title') }}</small>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('content') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                    {!! Form::label('content', 'Content') !!}
                    {!! Form::textarea('content', $project->content, ['class' => 'form-control', 'required' => 'required']) !!}
                    <small class="text-danger">{{ $errors->first('content') }}</small>
                </div>

                @if($project->progress == 1)
                <div class="radio{{ $errors->has('progress') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                    <label for="progress">
                        {!! Form::radio('progress', '1',  null, ['id' => 'radio_id', 'checked' => 'checked']) !!} In Progress
                    </label>
                    <small class="text-danger">{{ $errors->first('progress') }}</small>
                </div>

                <div class="radio{{ $errors->has('progress') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                    <label for="progress">
                        {!! Form::radio('progress', '2',  null, ['id' => 'radio_id']) !!} Complete
                    </label>
                    <small class="text-danger">{{ $errors->first('progress') }}</small>
                </div>
                @else
                <div class="radio{{ $errors->has('progress') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                    <label for="progress">
                        {!! Form::radio('progress', '1',  null, ['id' => 'radio_id']) !!} In Progress
                    </label>
                    <small class="text-danger">{{ $errors->first('progress') }}</small>
                </div>

                <div class="radio{{ $errors->has('progress') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                    <label for="progress">
                        {!! Form::radio('progress', '2',  null, ['id' => 'radio_id', 'checked' => 'checked']) !!} Complete
                    </label>
                    <small class="text-danger">{{ $errors->first('progress') }}</small>
                </div>
                @endif

                <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('image') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                    {!! Form::label('image', 'Select Image of page') !!}
                    {!! Form::file('image') !!}
                    <p class="help-block">for better view select 1920x1080 size of image</p>
                    <small class="text-danger">{{ $errors->first('image') }}</small>
                </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                      {!! Form::submit("Edit", ['class' => 'btn btn-warning pull-right']) !!}

                  {!! Form::close() !!}
```

And my admin panel

```
public function projectedit($id, Request $request){

    $this->validate($request, [
        'title' => 'required|max:255',
        'content' => 'required|max:10000',
        'image' => 'mimes:jpeg,bmp,png,jpg',
    ]);

    $project = Project::where('slug', $id)->firstorfail();
    $project->title = $request->title;
    $project->slug = str_slug($project->title, '-');
    $project->content = $request->content;
    $project->progress = $request->progress;
    if($request->hasFile('image')) {
        $file = Input::file('image');
        //getting timestamp
        $timestamp = str_replace([' ', ':'], '-', Carbon::now()->toDateTimeString());
        $name = $timestamp. '-' .$file->getClientOriginalName();
        $file->move(public_path().'/images/project/', $name);
        $project->image = $name;
        $thumb = Image::make(public_path().'/images/project/' . $name)->resize(1200,500)->save(public_path().'/images/project/thumb/' . $name, 60);
    }
    $project->save();
    return Redirect::back()->with('status', 'Project Edit Success');

}
```

Please tell me what I'm doing wrong everything is working fine but image not uploading and not uploading image only else everything is working fine.

Comment: Change `'files' => false`  to `'files' -> true`

Comment: You doing this: `'files' => 'false'` this restrict the image when uploading! Do: `'files' => 'true` to upload a file!

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should set

`'files' => 'false'`

to

`'files' => 'true'`

in Line 1 of your Form

Comment: you are right also Look on route its in array and route should not have files so i just change 'route' => ['admin.project.edit', $project->slug, 'files' => 'true'] to 'route' => ['admin.project.edit', $project->slug], 'files' => 'true' fix this on your code i will check on you

Answer (score 1):

Change following line:

```
{!! Form::open(['method' => 'PUT', 'route' => ['admin.project.edit', $project->slug, 'files' => 'false']]) !!}
```

to this:

```
{!! Form::open(['method' => 'PUT', 'route' => ['admin.project.edit', $project->slug], 'files' => 'true']) !!}
```

And the way you are uploading image is quite messy it looks in controller how about using [Laravel Filesystem](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/filesystem) for that?

Change following line in config/filesytems.php:

```
'local' => [
     'driver' => 'local',
     'root' => storage_path('app'),
],
```

to this:

```
'local' => [
     'driver' => 'local',
     'root' => public_path(),
],
```

Then in the controller you can do this:

```
public function projectedit($id, Request $request){
    $this->validate($request, [
        'title' => 'required|max:255',
        'content' => 'required|max:10000',
        'image' => 'mimes:jpeg,bmp,png,jpg',
    ]);

    $project = Project::where('slug', $id)->firstorfail();
    $project->title = $request->title;
    $project->slug = str_slug($project->title, '-');
    $project->content = $request->content;
    $project->progress = $request->progress;
    if($request->hasFile('image')) {
        $project->image = $request->file('image')->store('images/project');
    }
    $project->save();
    return Redirect::back()->with('status', 'Project Edit Success');
}
```

Clean right? :)

Comment: i found the answer Look on route its in array and route should not have files 
so i just change 'route' => ['admin.project.edit', $project->slug, 'files' => 'true'] to 'route' => ['admin.project.edit', $project->slug], 'files' => 'true' 
fix this on your code i will check on you

Comment: Look's like I got type in there, sorted out :) Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In your form creation code you set:

```
['files' => 'false']
```

This restricts file upload, when you change it to true, the generated form will have a encoding type of

```
enctype= multipart/form-data laravel
```

Answer (score 0):

set **'files' => 'false'** to **'files' => 'true'** in your form.

and check your php.ini file for the **file_upload=on;**

Answer (score 0):

Please change your form method like:

```
{!! Form::open(['method' => 'PUT', 'route' => ['admin.project.edit', $project->slug, 'files' => 'false']]) !!}
```

To

```
{!! Form::open(['method' => 'POST', 'route' => ['admin.project.edit', $project->slug, 'files' => 'true']]) !!}
```